# powershell script - timegenerated in security log

Tags: powershell

i need some help with this code, as i'm a super-beginner with powershell but trying to get a report to my manager who is looking to see failed external attempts to remote into our system.

trying to pull out 4625 events from the security log and get the following fields into a csv file: Username (if it's an internal user), date of event, origin IP. I have this code so far based on what i could find (a.k.a. leech) online and customized a bit. everything is correct at this point except for the date (timegenerated). and i believe it's because of the replacementstring number listed. it's pulling the SubjectUserSid from the log. i'm not quite sure i understand how to find that replacementstring number, so maybe if someone can explain that to me, that would help.
thanks

```
$Date = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-1)
$Server = "SERVER"
$logName = '{0}{1}_security4625_log.csv' -f "C:\temp\",
 $Date.tostring("MM-dd-yyyy_HH,mm,ss")

Get-EventLog -LogName 'Security' -Computer $Server `
 -InstanceId 4625 `
 -After $Date |
 Select-Object @{
  Name='TargetUserName'
  Expression={$_.ReplacementStrings[5]}
 },
 @{
  Name='WorkstationName'
  Expression={$_.ReplacementStrings[1] -replace '\$$'}
 },
 @{
  Name='IpAddress'
  Expression={$_.ReplacementStrings[-2]}
 },
 @{
  Name='TimeGenerated'
  Expression={$_.ReplacementStrings[0]}
 } |
 Export-Csv -Path $logName -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `@{Name='TimeGenerated';Expression={$_.ReplacementStrings[0]}` to simply `TimeGenerated` and you should be all set.

The `ReplacementStrings` are the variables from the `Message` field. Such as, the following log entry:

```
EventID            : 4656
MachineName        : AmazingLaptop.ChinchillaFarm.com
Data               : {}
Index              : 23277285
Category           : (12804)
CategoryNumber     : 12804
EntryType          : FailureAudit
Message            : A handle to an object was requested.

                     Subject:
                         Security ID:        S-1-5-21-2127521184-6397854128-1234567890-12345678
                         Account Name:        TMTech
                         Account Domain:        ChinchillaFarm
                         Logon ID:        0xb8f705b

                     Object:
                         Object Server:        SC Manager
                         Object Type:        SERVICE OBJECT
                         Object Name:        Schedule
                         Handle ID:        0x0
                         Resource Attributes:    -

                     Process Information:
                         Process ID:        0x2b4
                         Process Name:        C:\Windows\System32\services.exe

                     Access Request Information:
                         Transaction ID:        {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
                         Accesses:        %%7186
                                     %%7188

                         Access Reasons:        -
                         Access Mask:        0x14
                         Privileges Used for Access Check:    -
                         Restricted SID Count:    0
Source             : Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
ReplacementStrings : {S-1-5-21-2127521184-6397854128-1234567890-12345678, TMTech, ChinchillaFarm, 0xb8f705b...}
InstanceId         : 4656
TimeGenerated      : 11/20/2015 11:06:39 AM
TimeWritten        : 11/20/2015 11:06:39 AM
UserName           : 
Site               : 
Container          :
```

The ReplacementStrings are the values for all the fields like 'Security ID', 'Account Name', and 'Account Domain' within the Message property. Instead using one of those for the date/time you can just use the TimeGenerated property and it'll work just as well for your CSV.

Updated script:

```
$Date = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-1)
$Server = "SERVER"
$logName = '{0}{1}_security4625_log.csv' -f "C:\temp\",
 $Date.tostring("MM-dd-yyyy_HH,mm,ss")

Get-EventLog -LogName 'Security' -Computer $Server `
 -InstanceId 4625 `
 -After $Date |
 Select-Object @{
  Name='TargetUserName'
  Expression={$_.ReplacementStrings[5]}
 },
 @{
  Name='WorkstationName'
  Expression={$_.ReplacementStrings[1] -replace '\$$'}
 },
 @{
  Name='IpAddress'
  Expression={$_.ReplacementStrings[-2]}
 },
 TimeGenerated |
 Export-Csv -Path $logName -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: do you mean like this @TheMadTechnician
@{Name='TimeGenerated'}

Comment: oh literally just the word TimeGenerated! ok, let me give that a shot.

Comment: that works perfectly, thank you very much. worked on this for 2 days before asking.